# strong_parameters with rails 4.0.3 dependency error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, strong-parameters, mass-assignment

I have some issue about use strong parameters on Rails 4

I have on my gemfile

```
  gem 'rails', '4.0.3'
  gem "strong_parameters", "~> 0.2.3"
```

And when I run the bundler

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........
Fetching additional metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "actionpack":
  In Gemfile:

    strong_parameters (~> 0.2.3) ruby depends on
      actionpack (~> 3.0) ruby
    rails (= 4.0.3) ruby depends on
      actionpack (4.0.3)
```

I have tried:

- Re-run bundler
- Remove Gemfile.lock
- Reinstall all gemset without the gem, and re-add it

And nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `Rails 4.0+` , `strong_parameters gem` is no longer required as the functionality has been built-in within the Rails framework.

See the [strong_parameters official documentation](https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#compatibility) page for more details.